# img tag not reading url which is passed in src reactJS

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm recieving my img url from my DB like this

```
const [img,setImg] = useState()

 useEffect((): void => {
      axios
    .get(`http://localhost:4000/getUser/${match.params.userId}`)
    .then((users) => {
      dispatch(actions.getUser(users.data))
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('--------err', err);
    })
  

},[])
```

After this i setImg to the img like this :

```
 useEffect (() : void => {
setImg(avatar)
console.log('--------img', img);
  })
```

When i `console.log(img)` i get url like this `file:///home/user/Desktop/sql/uploads/avatar-1594717135245.jpeg.gif` .When I copy  it and paste it to the broswer I get img which shall be displayed,so URL Is correct.

Here is my img tag :  `<img ref={fileRef} src={img} width={'400'} alt={'picture'}/>` it is showing no errors in the console but the problem is it is not displaying the picture either.
Any suggestions please?

Comment: Its impossible, you need to upload the img and get an URL.

Comment: @DennisVash but is not this considered as url? `file:///home/user/Desktop/sql/uploads/avatar-1594717135245.jpeg.gif`

Comment: try returning a base-64 string instead. this will not work. you are saying a tag to read a local file (security vulnerability)

Comment: After importing url, add the following statement `import IMG from url` and use the src attribute of image tag as `src={IMG}`. Tell me if it works..